# Need help in java script code

Tags: javascript

```
            function addNumbers()
            {
                    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
                    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
                    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
                    ansD.value = val1 + val2;
            }
```

I want to show the output without click on a button please help me out.

Comment: What should trigger the calculation?

Comment: addNumbers() This is a function which is calculating amounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onchange`, this will trigger the function, once the `input` is blurred. Or you can use `onkeyup`, this will be triggered as you type.

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
  var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
  var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
  ansD.value = val1 + val2;
}
window.onload = function() {
 addNumbers();
};
```

```html
<input id="value1" onkeyup='addNumbers()' value="10"/>
<input id="value2" onkeyup='addNumbers()' value="20"/>
<input id="answer" />
```

**Edit:**

You can also do a check if `value` in `input` exists using some conditions(if needed) if you don't want to display `NaN` when one value is empty.

Comment: <input id="value1" onkeyup='addNumbers()' value="10" />
<input id="value2" onkeyup='addNumbers()' value="20" />
<input id="answer" />

I changed your triger but my HTML form fields are like this

Comment: @Harsimransingh. In that case you can call the function on page load. See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4pwsptqL/ . I updated answer. Plz accect the answer if it works for you.